# Need clarification for Sonicwall "Public Server" wizard NAS policies

Tags: networking, router, firewall, nat

I used the SonicWall TZ105 "Public Server" wizard to add NAT policies for an internal (non-DMZ) server, but I do not understand the need for all the Custom policies that resulted:

```
#   Source                     Destin.                 Service               Interface
    Original      Translated   Original   Translated   Original  Translated  In   Out
--  ------------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------- ----------- ---  ---
1   Firewalled    MyServer     MyServer   MyServer     MyServer  Original    Any  Any
    Subnets       Public       Public     Private      Services

2   MyServer      MyServer     Any        Original     MyServer  Original    Any  X1
    Private       Public                               Services

3   Any           Original     MyServer   MyServer     MyServer  Original    Any  Any
                               Public     Private      Services

4   Any           WAN          Any        Original     Any       Original    X0   X1
                  Primary IP
```

Policy 4 seems to be the general rule that allows all internal hosts to access the internet using the public/WAN IP.

Policy 3 seems to allow incoming connections to access the server, which I definitely need since that is what I am trying to accomplish.

Policy 2 seems to ensure that any outgoing connections by the server services are mapped to the correct WAN IP address? If we only have a single IP address, is this necessary? Without this rule, wouldn't the server's outbound connections simply be mapped with rule #4?

Policy 1 seems to match attempts by internal hosts to reach the server using the WAN IP and maps the IP address back to the internal IP address, preventing internal traffic from leaving the internal network? Is that correct? If so, how important is such a rule given that the internal network has DNS and the hostname will resolve to the private IP address on our network. Would this rule come into effect if SSLVPN is used to access the network and access the service?

Since we have multiple servers behind this firewall, I am trying to keep the policies screen as uncluttered as possible, and would like to avoid adding policies like 1 and 2 if they are already effectively covered by policies like 4 and our internal DNS server. I do not expect we will get an additional IP addresss.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the order you listed:

Policy 4: You are correct.

Policy 3: You are correct.

Policy 2: You're pretty much correct.  If you only have one public IP, all traffic will be NATed to it.  This is an explicit rule which is helpful when you have a range of public IPs and different services on different IPs.

Policy 1:  This rule is a hairpin NAT rule that redirects internal clients back to the private IP, as you indicated.  If an internal client uses a different DNS server than yours, they will not get the internal address, they'll get the public IP.  That's why this rule is necessary.

You might be able to get by without Policy 1 and 2, but it may not be worth the trouble down the road if you make changes.